# Create new mapped columns from list

Tags: python

I have two dataframes (df1 & df2) and I need to bring in all the columns from df2 into df1 except for the first column ItemNum. The columns in df2 will be new columns in df1. This code works well to bring in one at a time:

```
df1['Color'] = df1['ItemNum'].map(df2.set_index('ItemNum')['Color'])
```

However, I wanted to make this faster, so I made a list of all the columns in df2. I wanted to iterate through it, skipping the first column. Now I get the error: "['ItemNum'] not in index"

```
df2_col_list = list(df2)

for x in df2_col_list:
if df2_col_list!= ['ItemNum']:
    df1[df2_col_list] = df1['ItemNum'].map(df2.set_index('ItemNum')[df2_col_list])
```

What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 0):

To join two dataframes use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and to remove a column use [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2.drop('ItemNum', axis=1)], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Comment: That didn't work.  It didn't map correctly and it now has the same number of rows as df2, which is a shorter list because its ItemNum has no duplicates, df1 does.